# What does "biting one's nails" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

It is puzzling. When I search online for "what is nail biting" all I get are pages explaining how to stop, not *what it is*.

Is it simply the act of biting the nails, or does it necessarily include a compulsive element to it? If someone trims their nails by biting, does it count? If they trim their nails, but don't bite their nails any time else, does it count?

Are all of the forms of "nail biting" mention equally as problematic? Is nail biting an issue in social acceptance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used literally, which is common, "biting one's nails" refers to using one's physical teeth to bite one's physical nails, regardless of the reason or frequency. E.g. "Look, Sally is biting her nails" means "Look, Sally is using her teeth to cut/tear off the ends of her fingernails".

Therefore:

> does it necessarily include a compulsive element to it?

No.

> If someone trims their nails by biting, does it count? If they trim their nails, but don't bite their nails any time else, does it count?

Yes, that would still be called "biting one's nails".

---

In my portion of the English-speaking world, it isn't considered socially normal to trim one's nails by biting. It's expected to use a sharp instrument to do the job: most people use metal nail clippers, some might use some other tool such as scissors or a knife. Children who bite their nails are expected to grow out of it as they get older, and if they don't, it is usually seen as a problem that parents should work to solve. That is the reason why you see search results about how to stop, or help someone else stop biting their nails.

Whether either nail-biting or the societal norms about it are problematic or an issue is not a question about English usage.

Because nail-biting is associated with anxiety, "biting one's nails" also has a metaphorical usage meaning "feeling anxious" (e.g. "I was biting my nails about X" = "I was anxious about X").

Answer (score 1):

"Nail biting" can be considered a [sign of agitation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/nail-biting). As far as OCD behavior, that is a question for psychology, rather than language use. As for connotation in a social context, it is not considered sanitary, in public, nor does it leave one's *finger*nails with a good appearance. However, *toe*nail biting might be considered a mark of great agility and flexibility.